# How to limit the background-image width/height of my custom bullet list background?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to do a custom bullet list. However, I want to use the same `background-image`, but changing the `background-position` (to give a cool effect)

The CSS I have is:

```
#sidebar ul{
    width:190px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#sidebar li{
    border-top:1px dashed #ddd;
    background:#FAFAFA url('./images/bullet.png') no-repeat 15px 9px;
}

#sidebar li:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    background-position:15px 0px;
}

#sidebar li a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px 20px 5px 26px; /*26 to give extra 6px for the bullet*/
}
```

The bullet changes correctly, and everything is ok. Except that both bullets are always visible :(

I want to know if there is a way to hide the other bullet.

An option could be to spread the images very far away (more than the height will ever be), but this is just a bad idea, and I don't want to have a big image size.

I am open for other methods, if the way I am trying to do is just not good and you know a better way, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to do something like this. Adjust values to your needs.

```
<li><span></span></li>
```

.

```
li { position: relative; }
li span { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: url('img.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
li:hover span { background-position: 0 -16px; }
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of empty tags, (I heard that it gives bad ranking on search engines). But  think I will do this anyway. EDIT: I think i will either put the link inside, or do the same but with my link instead of a span

Comment: The way you have it setup now isn't ideal since the background spans the width of `li` that's why you see both at the same time. For a css sprite to work properly, you need a fixed width & height, that's why the empty tag.

Comment: I see, :( well, empty tag it is